# Node.JS Server Cuts Off Frequently?

Tags: stream, node.js, websocket

I have a Node JS Server where I am using Socket.IO to stream content to the browser.  It works great for about 45 minutes or so of streaming, then it will usually cut out.  There are no "errors" reported in the terminal and the Node server acts like it is in, however the page I am serving clearly stops working.

What are my options for trying to get to the bottom of this?  Could this be a configuration issue with Node/Socket.IO?  is there any basic error logging you would recommend I setup?

Comment: Can you provide any sample code for the failing part of your server?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your code, but Socket.IO for NodeJS requires a heartbeat to maintain connection.  It could be a bug in the client code for sending the heartbeat.